# Import error tensorflow-gpu in ubuntu18.04

Tags: python, tensorflow, nvidia, ubuntu-18.04

I'm getting some error while importing tensorflow.

My computer's Specifications:

OS:ubuntu 18.04

Nvidia RTX 2080 Ti*2

Nvidia driver-415

CUDA：10.0

cuDNN：7.3.0
tensorflow：1.11.0

```
import tensorflow
```

Error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py",
>   line 58, in 
>       from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 28, in 
>       _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 24, in swig_import_helper
>       _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 243,
>   in load_module
>       return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
>       return _load(spec) ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>      File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/**init**.py", line
>   22, in 
>       from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/**init**.py",
>   line 49, in 
>       from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py",
>   line 74, in 
>       raise ImportError(msg) ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py",
>   line 58, in 
>       from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 28, in 
>       _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 24, in swig_import_helper
>       _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 243,
>   in load_module
>       return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
>       return _load(spec) ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>
> Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
>
> See
>   https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems
>
> for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
>   above this error message when asking for help.

I already tried to use ubuntu 16.04 ,but GPU didn't support.
Installation of CUDA9.0 & CUDA9.2 was not supported too.

how can I use tensorflow-gpu?

I already app path in ~/.bashrc

```
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-10.0/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-10.0/lib64${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}
export CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda-10.0
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-10.0/lib64
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-10.0/lib64$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Comment: Have you tried using conda to install tensorflow-gpu? after creating an environment you could try installing several tensorflow-gpu versions until you get one that works, e.g. conda install tensorflow-gpu, conda install tensorflow-gpu=1.13, conda install tensorflow-gpu=1.12, etc

Answer (score 1):

The `tensorflow-gpu` package is built against Cuda 9.0, but you have Cuda 10.0 installed.

You need either to downgrade your version of Cuda to 9.0 (but if I recall, that's not possible with a 2080Ti), or build tensorflow from the sources. There is extensive documentation on how to do so on the [tensorflow webiste](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source)

You can also try to install the package `tf-nightly-gpu`. You should note that this version is more experimental though, as it has not been tested as extensively.